# Get last N rows ordered ascending without using nested SELECTs

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to get the last N rows in ascending order. Is it possible without using nested SELECTs?

The reason of this question if it is know if there is other way more efficient.

Nested selects:

```
select id, timestamp, col3, col4
from (
      select * from t_myTable
      order by timestamp DESC LIMIT 5
     ) as d 
order by timestamp ASC
```

The `id` column is auto-incremental.
thanks.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: What's the problem with your current query? Why do you want to change it if it does what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need two different orderings, I cannot imagine that there is a different way to do it without a subquery. And even if there were, I am pretty confident that that query would be more complicated and would perform worse.

Comment: thanks. I am not an expert and I wanted to know if there was other more efficient way for to do it. thanks.